# I am trying to swap images in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to swap the src image with the id image. From what I see on other examples I thought this would be the way to go about doing it. It definitely does not work for me. This is my first time posting here so any help with formatting my question would be greatly appreciated also.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Rollovers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="rollover.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Image Rollovers</h1>
        <ul id="image_rollovers">
            <li><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="" id="images/h5.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
        </ul>        
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//FUNCTION
var $ = function (id) { 
        return document.getElementById(id); 
}       

//MOUSE EVENT FUNCTIONS
var rollover = function(evt) {
    var link = this;
    var imageNode = $("img");
    imageNode.setAttribute("img", link.getAttribute("id"));
}

var rollout = function(evt) {
    var link = this;
    var imageNode = $("id");
    imageNode.setAttribute("id", link.getAttribute("img"));
}

//ONLOAD EVENT HANDLER      
window.onload = function () {

        //GET ALL IMG TAGS
        var linkNode = $("image_rollovers");
        var images = linkNode.getElementsByTagName("img");
        //PROCESS EACH IMAGE
        var i, linkNode, image;
        for ( i=0; i<images.length; i++)
        {
            linkNode = images[i];
            linkNode.onmouseover = rollover;
            linkNode.onmouseout = rollout; 
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the editing help! It is much appreciated.

Comment: `linkNode.getElementsByTagName("src")` should be `linkNode.getElementsByTagName("img")`

Comment: You're also missing the `>` at the end of the third `<img`

Comment: Ah yes because the tag is img. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo in the HTML, you're missing the `>` at the end of the third `<img`.

```
        <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
                                                              ^
```

Second, you're calling `$("img")` and `$("id")`, but there are no elements with those IDs. You should just be setting a variable to the appropriate attribute of `link`. There's no need for different functions for `rollover` and `rollout`, since they both just swap the `id` and `src` attributes.

```
//MOUSE EVENT FUNCTIONS
function swap_src_and_id(evt) {
    var link = this;
    var src = link.getAttribute("src");
    link.setAttribute("src", link.getAttribute("id"));
    link.setAttribute("id", src);
}
```

Third, you're calling `linkNode.getElementsByTagName("src")`, but there's no such tag. It should be `img`.

```
window.onload = function () {

    //GET ALL IMG TAGS
    var linkNode = $("image_rollovers");
    var images = linkNode.getElementsByTagName("img");
    //PROCESS EACH IMAGE
    var i, linkNode, image;
    for ( i=0; i<images.length; i++)
    {
        linkNode = images[i];
        linkNode.onmouseover = swap_src_and_id;
        linkNode.onmouseout = swap_src_and_id; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the first part was just lazy on my part. I tried to alter the HTML to add a mouseover event and just deleted too much.

This code makes so much more sense when its written out. How come in the second link.setAttribute you dont need getAttribute?

Comment: @BenStone I used `getAttribute` when I set the variable `src`.